# Rufus-Scheduler Running Only Once

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I am using Rufus Scheduler to run another Ruby script every two minutes. The script runs once, but never again. Is there an error in my code? HTOP shows that "launcher.rb" continues to exist as a process after the "script.rb" code runs once.

```
#launcher.rb

require "rubygems"
require "rufus-scheduler"

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new    

scheduler.every("2m")do
    require "/home/pi/Bots/script.rb"
end

scheduler.join
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with

```
#launcher.rb

require "rubygems"
require "rufus-scheduler"

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every("2m")do
  #require "/home/pi/Bots/script.rb"
  load "/home/pi/Bots/script.rb"
end

scheduler.join
```

It may work ("may" because I don't know exactly what's in your script.rb). `require` will not load and run again whatever behind your "home/pi/Bots/script.rb" while `load` will load and run each time.

What happens with your current launcher is that require is called every 2 minutes, but only the first time does it load and run the script.rb.

Please note that the following might be better:

```
# script.rb

module MyBot
  def self.call
    # do the job...
  end
end


# launcher.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require '/home/pi/Bots/script.rb'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every('2m') do
  MyBot.call
end

scheduler.join
```

See [Kernel#load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Kernel.html#method-i-load) and [Kernel#require](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

Comment: Your "load" vs "require" suggestion solved the problem. Many thanks for your help, as well as for all your work on Rufus--it is a great piece of software!